# relation between coplanarity and collinear

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

According to my textbook ,if a and b are two vectors which are non zero and non collinear  then any vector coplanar with them can be expressed as r=xa+yb.

Does this mean that if three vectors are coplanar then they are non-collinear and also why can't collinear vectors be coplanar?

Comment: Coplanar vectors _can_ be collinear. And collinear vectors are _always_ coplanar.

Comment: It looks like you're misinterpreting the logic of an if-then type statement.

Comment: i just went by the definition by the book ...that's why i am asking for a detailed answer as i know i am confused.it will be kind if you post an answer for my question.

Comment: So if vectors are collinear so we can always get a plane where the vectors or their displacement can lie ?

Comment: Yes, just take any new vector which is not collinear, and form a plane.

Comment: thanx,that clears my doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any 2 non-collinear vectors create a plane, means that any 2 vectors that non-collinear are linearly independent. so any vector in the plane can be created by linear combination of those 2. this is what your book say

let's say what collinear is: 2 vectors are collinear if they are on the same line

now what coplanar is: 2 vectors are coplanar if they are on the same plane

so collinear vectors ARE coplanar but coplanar vectors CAN BE collinear.

Comment: kay i understood what you were saying but how exactly does two vectors create plane?I am new to this topic so i don't know much details about these things.

Comment: @user42172 think about the x-axis and y-axis in 2D graph. Now think about 2 vectors, one will be a vector with the length of one and in the direction of the x-axis and one is the same length with the direction of the y-axis. So any point on the plane(the whole graph) is equal to the x value of the point times the first vector and the y value of the point times the second vector. This is an example for 2 perpendicular vectors but it works simularly with any 2 non-collinear(it can be more generalize after you'll learn more about linearly independent vectors)

Comment: this  really helped me a lot but i couldn't unnderstand the part  the length of the planes.Is tihe vector whose direction is in x axis extend upto its length and same with y axis.

Comment: @user42172 the 2 vectors have length of 1. Maybe an example will help. The vectors will be called $x_0,y_0$: let's say I have the point $(3,7)$(3 is the x-axis and 7 the y-axis) I can say that that point is $3x_0+7y_0$ like wise I can do for every point on the graph. So those 2 vectors creat a plane

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vector+space+span&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGhvS4yZjXAhWHpY8KHYu7CQ4Q_AUICigB&biw=1067&bih=529#imgrc=uq5xGPc5lBWpmM: In this example ,the two vectors spanning the plane are not of unit length infact they have different length so the will  plane still be forme even if they have different length?

Comment: Also do these vectors decide how the plane will direct i e  span in direction?

Comment: @user42172 the length is doesn't matter, the thing is that one vector times a number(scalar) plus the other vector times a number(scalar) can get you to every point on the plane.if the vector is two times longer then the number will be 2 times less(times 0.5)

Comment: @user42172 well, in higher dimensions yes, the way vectors decide the "direction" of the plane(it is not exactly direction but it is close enough for now) but in 2 dimensions the plane is the WHOLE graph so no, in 2D it doesn't matter

Comment: Can we say the same for collinear vectors for eg if there are two collinear vectors then there will be infinite number of planes passing through them so they are coplanar?

Comment: @user42172 exactly, this is why collinear vectors ARE coplanar, but you can't say the opposite

Comment: This pretty much solves my doubt...Thank you for your clear answers.